# constexpt function with anonymous union in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Всем привет!

Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
// Source.hpp

/**
 * @brief Method that checks the endian type on the system.
 * @return DATA_LITTLE_ENDIAN(0x02) - if on the system little endian, otherwise - DATA_BIG_ENDIAN(0x01).
 */
static inline DATA_ENDIAN_TYPE CheckSystemEndian(void) noexcept
{
    const union {
        const uint16_t value;
        const uint8_t data[sizeof(uint16_t)];
    } endian { 0x0102 };
    return static_cast<DATA_ENDIAN_TYPE>(endian.data[0]);
}

Class Foo
{
    static const DATA_ENDIAN_TYPE system_endian;
}

// Source.cpp
inline const DATA_ENDIAN_TYPE BinaryDataEngine::system_endian = CheckSystemEndian();
```

**Что требуется:**
Мне хочется решать эту задачу в `compile-time`, следовательно необходимо переделать функция `CheckSystemEndian()` на `constexp`. Однако в этой задаче мне очень мешает `union`.

**Ошибка следующая:**

> constexpr function never produces a constant expression.
>   Read of member 'data' of union with active member 'value' is not allowed in a constant expression.

Подсткажите, пожалуйста, способ, как можно добиться требуемой функциональности в `compile-time`.
Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, что не получится добиться подобного функционала. `constexpr` имеет свойство быть независимым от компилятора/платформы

Comment: Если используется gcc, то можно воспользоваться макросом `#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` и далее по тексту https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html Для студии похожая портянка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113768/visual-studio-determine-endianness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, определить порядок байт (endianness) на этапе компиляции невозможно в принципе (стандартными средствами). Тут нужен `reinterpret_cast`, а он не считается `constexpr` выражением.

В С++20 для этого появится `std::endian`, и можно будет писать так:

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool is_big_endian    = std::endian::native == std::endian::big;
constexpr bool is_little_endian = std::endian::native == std::endian::little;
```

Дожидаясь С++20, можно использовать нестандартные фичи компиляторов. Например, GCC умеет так:

```
constexpr bool is_big_endian    = __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__;
constexpr bool is_little_endian = __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__;
```

---

Кроме того, у вас в программе неопределенное поведение, ведь С++, в отличие от С, не позволяет читать из неактивного поля union'а. [Пруф.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)

Вот пример, как можно исправить код:

```
static inline DATA_ENDIAN_TYPE CheckSystemEndian(void) noexcept
{
    const uint16_t value = 0x0102;
    return static_cast<DATA_ENDIAN_TYPE>((uint8_t &)value);
}
```

К тому же, так он еще и места меньше занимает.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант а ля **cmake** или **Lisp**, мне больше нравится Лисп.

```
Makefile :
...
clean:
 ...TAB... @rm endian.hpp endian ...
endian.hpp: endian.cpp
 ...TAB... @g++ --std=c++11 endian.cpp -o endian
 ...TAB... @./endian > endian.hpp
...

endian.cpp :
# include <iostream>
volatile uint16_t const v16  { 0x0102  } ;
volatile uint8_t const * pv8 { reinterpret_cast < volatile uint8_t const * > ( & v16 ) } ;
bool const little_endian { (  * pv8 ) == 0x02 } ;
bool const big_endian { ( * pv8 ) == 0x01 } ;
int main  ( )  {
  if(little_endian) std::cout<<"# define MY_LITTLE_ENDIAN "<<std::endl;
  else std::cout<<"# define MY_BIG_ENDIAN "<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"bool constexpr little_endian { "<<(little_endian ? "true" : "false")<<" } ;"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"bool constexpr big_endian { "<<(big_endian ? "true" : "false")<<" } ;"<<std::endl; }
```